# Django ModelAdmin perform extra operations

Tags: django, django-admin

Should I use save_model to do extra operations before I save a record?

When an error occur, how can I stop the function to save a record and prompt an error on top of the ModelAdmin form?

Comment: Depends on what type of error you are talking about. Are you talking about validation checks?

Comment: Yes, check some data from database, if not valid, prompt error and stop execution immediately.

Comment: Then you should check it during form validation.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is better to use [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) instead of overriding save.

And for the validation part you should  define a `ModelForm` and add your [validation rules](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) there.

Form Validation is explained [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

```
def clean_name(self):
    # do something that validates your data
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    name = cleaned_data.get("name")
    if not name:
        raise forms.ValidationError('please add your name')
    return name
```